# Getting the scalar speed from an X and Y velocity

Tags: physics, algorithm, vector, linear-algebra, trigonometry

Given a `Vector2(x,y)` that represents an object's velocity, like so:

```js
let angle = Math.PI / 2;
let speed = 500;
let velocity = new Vector2();

velocity.x = Math.cos(angle) * speed;
velocity.y = Math.cos(angle) * speed;
```

How can you retrieve the speed?

```js
let angle = Math.atan2(velocity.y, velocity.x);
// let speed = ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the answer as:

```js
let speed = Math.sqrt(velocity.x ** 2 + velocity.y ** 2)
```